# Strange concurrency behaviour on Java 6 Mac OS X Lion

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, osx-lion, synchronized

I've been experimenting with difference between intrinsic locks and `java.util.concurrent.ReentrantLock` for some time now. I've found very strange thing. Consider following code:

```
public class WriteOnceRunAnywhere {

    private static long counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final int numThreads = 2;
        final int numIterations = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        Runnable inc = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {

                    increment();

                    if (i % 10000000 == 0)
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            new Thread(inc).start();
    }

    public static synchronized void increment() {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Simple thing, no fancy stuff. Right? Happens to break!
Most likely when you run it, it won't end. After some ping-pong between threads you'll see
only one thread is actually running. The other *hangs* forever:

> Thread-1 Thread-2 Thread-1 Thread-2 Thread-1 ... Thread-2 Thread-2
>   Thread-2 Thread-2 Thread-2 Thread-2 Thread-2 Thread-2 Thread-2 ...

After that, java process can't accept `jvisualvm` connection. CPU load drops and continuously stays at about 1.0%.

> Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (11C74), 2.53 GHz Intel Core i5
>
> java version "1.6.0_29" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)

Can someone tell me what the heck is happening here?

**UPD** Looks like the bug will be fixed in 1.6.30 [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088122/381105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are observing an existing bug in Mac OS 7 JDK 1.6.  You can see the same issue occurred here:

http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-January/008778.html

You may want to read from the start at

http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-January/008759.html

Finally there seems to be a resolution in for Open JDK 7.

http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-January/008789.html

Long story short. It will only fail with JDK 1.6_14 (or greater < JDK 7) and Max OS 7.  Their test and the results you are seeing are very similar.

I am guessing you can't even get a jstack or load jconsole?

Comment: @pavelrappo Youre welcome.  This is almost certainly an issue with the JVM.  In those links there is code that they ran that worked - you can try that to confirm.   Finally if you run the same code in JDK 7 it should work fine.

Comment: @pavelrapppo after you are not able to takea jstack does Thread-2 keep printing or does it freeze

Comment: It keeps printing. The possibility to attach with `jvisualvm` is lost after Thread-1 stops printing.

Comment: I built open-jdk7. No bug found. Looks like it's exactly what you told me.

Comment: @pavelrappo Great! Hopefully they patch that issue in JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off `-XX:-UseBiasedLocking`  It probably ping-pongs until the code is optimised (try `-XX:+PrintCompilation` and then it effectively determines the program will run faster if only one thread holds the lock. e.g. the synchronized is effectively moved outside the loop.

You will see this behaviour often when you using multiple threads to do something which is faster to do single threaded.

---

You can either have each thread alternatively increment the value or you can have one loop run until it stops (at Integer.MAX_VALUE) and then the second one.

```
public class CountingWithThreads {
    static long count1 = 0;
    static long count2 = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start1 = System.nanoTime();
        Thread t1a = new Thread(new CountsSingleThreaded(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        Thread t1b = new Thread(new CountsSingleThreaded(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        t1a.start();
        t1b.start();
        t1a.join();
        t1b.join();
        long time1 = System.nanoTime() - start1;
        System.out.printf("Single threaded, took %.1f second to count to %,d%n", time1 / 1e9, count1);

        long start2 = System.nanoTime();
        Thread t2a = new Thread(new CountsAlternatively(true, 1000000));
        Thread t2b = new Thread(new CountsAlternatively(false, 1000000));
        t2a.start();
        t2b.start();
        t2a.join();
        t2b.join();
        long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
        System.out.printf("Alternating multi-threaded took %.1f second to count to %,d%n", time2 / 1e9, count2);

    }

    static class CountsSingleThreaded implements Runnable {
        private final long maxValue;

        CountsSingleThreaded(long maxValue) {
            this.maxValue = maxValue;
        }

        public void run() {
            synchronized (CountingWithThreads.class) {
                for (long i = 0; i < maxValue; i++) {
                    count1++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class CountsAlternatively implements Runnable {
        private final boolean even;
        private final long maximum;

        CountsAlternatively(boolean even, long maximum) {
            this.even = even;
            this.maximum = maximum;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (CountingWithThreads.class) {
                    while (count2 < maximum)
                        if (((count2 & 1) == 0) == even) {
                            count2++;
                            CountingWithThreads.class.notify();
                        } else {
                            CountingWithThreads.class.wait();
                        }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Single threaded, took 2.3 second to count to 4,294,967,294
Alternating multi-threaded took 3.4 second to count to 1,000,000
```

Running one thread to completion one at a time is the most efficient.  If you force strict alternating of the counters (the most extreme example of mult-threading) it is over 1000x slower.

Comment: @Pater Lawrey I've already tried biased locking option -- same stuff

Comment: In that case, I suspect the loop optimisation. See if the method is compiled just before the behaviour changes.

Comment: Where the heck are my JMM guarantees?

Comment: like I said, the JIT identifies its faster to use one thread at a time.  I suggest you try finding an example where its faster using two threads than one.

Comment: You basically say it's ok to do half of the work only because it's faster than doing all the work, right? JIT can optimise anything it wants as soon as the result of the optimised code is the same as result of not optimised one.

Comment: @pavelrappo Your code tries to do an infinite amount of work. Half an infinite quantity is the same as the whole quantity.

Comment: @David Schwartz why do you think it's inf?

Comment: @pavelrappo The guarantee you get is that your code will make forward progress. You don't get a guarantee that it will make forward progress through any particular path. (Though in this case, I think your actual problem is a bug.) It may not be literally infinite in this case, but it may be large enough as makes no practical difference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry I still disagree with you. If the algorithm supposed to get `4,294,967,294` (`2*(2^32-1)` inside long `conter` in the end and infinitely stays at some value smaller than that -- it's definitely a bug

Comment: @DavidSchwartz though I understand we're not talking about realtime systems, I still expect some kind of stability here.

Comment: Its is stable, just not the way you want. ;)

Comment: @pavelrappo If it infinitely stays at some value smaller than that because your code has an infinite amount of work to do other than incrementing that value, then it's not a bug. You are only guaranteed forward progress. It's your responsibility to write your code to make the forward progress you want. If you care about the order in which work is done, it is your responsibility to write code that does the work in that order. The implementation has no way to know that you don't really want it to do the work you asked it to do and would prefer it do some other work you also asked it to do.

Answer (score 0):

We have a developer preview that (among other things) fixes some low level synchronization problems.  If you've had problems with synchronization on Mac JDK6, please test this preview with your code and see if it fixes the problem on your hardware.  Thanks.

The developer preview is live: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Java%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X%20Developer%20Preview.